# Loop through JSON Array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I have a JSON array that I'm passing to PHP. Eventually I'll be passing and receiving alot more from my PHP file but for the moment this is it. Right now it's recieving 1 array and sending back that same array, no problem. I can loop through the data in Javascript but how do I loop through the array I pass to my PHP file? I get errors with foreach and a for loop didn't seem to help any. Suggestions?

**Javascript**

```
var fullName = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe"];

$(window).load(function(){
    getList();
});

function getList(){
    $.getJSON(
        "names.php",
        {names : JSON.stringify(fullName)},
        function(data) 
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.test.length; i++)
            {
                window.alert(data.test[i]);
            }
        }
      );
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $names=json_decode($_REQUEST['names']);

foreach($names as $name)
{
    echo $name;
}

    $data['test'] = $names;
    echo json_encode($data);
```

The foreach errors out on the foreach line telling me "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Which error do you get with that for-loop? And also please post the received JSON (inspect it at the network panel of your dev tools)

Comment: @Bergi tells me that there's an invalid argument. I'll update my code with the foreach in it.

Comment: In your PHP, `$names` should be an array.  What's the problem with reading it?

Comment: Invalid argument? To what? Is it a PHP or a JS error? Please post the exact error message, including the line it points to.

Comment: Updated. It's on PHP and points directly to the foreach line.

Comment: var_dump($names) - is it an array? is there anything?

Comment: What do `var_dump($_REQUEST['names']);` and `var_dump($names);` give you?

Comment: I'm getting NULL from the var_dump, but if that's the case how am I getting alerts back from the `success` of the jquery?

Comment: `success` in jquery just means that the script was called without any problems. It does not mean there are no errors in the script itself.

Comment: I suspect issue with the json stringify.see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @jeroen right but I'm sending back the `$names` array to my success function and alerting out the values. Where else could it get those values except from the PHP array?

Comment: Sounds like `json_decode` returned `null` for some reason. Btw, the returned JSON will be invalidated by `echo`ing random values before it...

Comment: @Howdy_McGee What exactly gets alerted?

Comment: @Shridhar is there some kind of alternative to stringify?

Comment: @jeroen "John Doe" and "Jane Doe"

Comment: That's kind of impossible with that code as you assign `NULL` to `$data['test']`. Is that the complete script?

Comment: @jeroen http://www.webdevstl.com/misc/ajax/

Comment: @jeroen maybe not impossible, because fullName is always initialized on the load, meaning that it will alert these even though $data['test'] is NULL

Comment: You can use it but make sure variable  full name  is formed correct object . I think it either missing {} or not array object . I am away from pc so can't tell correct syntax .

Comment: @art2 And how would `fullName` end up in the `data.test` variable that is alerted?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I mean, is that the complete php script?

Comment: @jeroen 100% the full script. It only works when I don't have the foreach in there though since it errors out on the foreach as mentioned earlier. I was having this problem in a bigger project so broke it down to the bare minimum which is this here.

Comment: So if `var_dump($names);` is `NULL`, what does `var_dump($data);` give you right before you `echo` it?

Comment: @jeroen I have no idea how things are being alerted out in my javascript when everything in PHP is null. I've var_dump'd everything, `$names`, `$data`, and `$data['test']` all at their respective places and get `NULL array(1) { ["test"]=> NULL } NULL {"test":null}`

Comment: are you sure that you are calling to the proper URL? Without a leading slash it might (not necessarily) result in 404 instead.
what I mean, is ... is the response code a 200 or a 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode()` doesn't return an array. To get it to do so you'd need to do `json_decode($_REQUEST['names'], true)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: that's true, but as the sample data looks like it's already an array.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something strange going on when using:

```
{names : JSON.stringify(fullName)}
```

As you are sending key - value pairs using `GET` or `POST`, you probably need to encode the value correctly.

You could do that using:

```
{names : encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(fullName))}
```

Comment: Still no luck with that. My `var_dumps` still show NULL. Maybe I need to use a different ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: jQuery is being insane again.

```
$.getJSON("names.php?names=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(fullName)), function(data)
        {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.test.length; i++)
                {
                        window.alert(data.test[i]);
                }
        }
);
```

The problem was it was adding each item in the array as seperate value to URI.

Comment: No luck with this either. It even breaks the alerts that would otherwise work (even though it shouldn't)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$names=json_decode($_POST['names']); // or $_GET
```

instead of

```
$names=json_decode($_REQUEST['names']);
```

Sometimes $_REQUEST can be empty because of php.ini conf. SEE [request_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
In your javascript function replace below line with

```
 {names : JSON.stringify(fullName)},
```

with

```
"{names :"+ JSON.stringify(fullName) +"}",
```

---

debug test

```
var fullName = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'];
console.log({names : JSON.stringify(fullName)});
// gives Object { names="["John Doe","Jane Doe"]"}
```

but with

```
console.log("{names :"+ JSON.stringify(fullName) +"}");
// gives {names :["John Doe","Jane Doe"]}
```

// so i guess second is correct json string to pass

Comment: When I use the `console.log` as suggested I do get `{names :["John Doe","Jane Doe"]} ` but in my PHP i'm still getting Nulls when I var_dump.

Comment: Ok, try one step back, we will remove full name array for a time being and just pass {names : "my test name1"}, and check if you get correct value in php script.  if you get correct value that means we have identified an issue with array to json string. otherwise there some other issues

Comment: Still nothing in PHP, all nulls. There gotta be something really wrong but I've used a similar script before. I'm just going to try from scratch with the ajax method mentioned below...

Answer (score 0):

```
/* client-side */
$.ajax({

   /* the request's method: */
   type: 'GET',

   /* the request's location: */
   url:'/names.php',

   /* the request's fields: */
   data: JSON.stringify({names: fullName}),

   /* the request's content-type : */
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

   /* the response's content-type: */
   dataType:'json',

   /* the callback function */ 
   success: function(json){

     if(json.length > 0){
         $.each(json, function(i, v){

            console.info(v);

         });
      }
      else {
         alert('wtf?!');
      }
});

/* server-side */
$req=array_merge($_GET, $_POST);

// die(print_r($req));

$names=json_decode($req['names']);
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf8;');
echo json_encode($names);
```

Alternatively one could set the request-method for the request, I'm just a little lazy and with that array_merge() it just doesn't matter if the request was a POST or GET (well, function $.ajax defaults to GET). Best practice is to use FireBug and checkout it's net-panel, especially the XHR tab. Probably the question should have been: "How to use a XHR debugger?" because there's nothing tricky about this at all.

It seems that the jQuery API has been slightly updated (see the Deprecation Notice):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

https://getfirebug.com

Comment: If FireBug doesn't work ... you must be missing something fundamental.
This code and above posted codes should both "work" - at least log anything to JS console.

Comment: besides "doesn't work" isn't considered an error description... while you're not telling where exactly the request bugs out - this is only guessing around. at least it's an example how to create the proper headers for request & response... and FireBug (should) display in detail what happens.

Comment: Have you ever used a JS debugger, seriously?? It's all somewhat obvious when setting watches for certain variables and some breakpoints, e.g. on callback.

Comment: just set a watch on $ or jQuery ... and you can inspect jQuery itself

Comment: I suppose I must admit that the problem doesn't seem to be with the Jquery at all and with the PHP. Good rant through.

Comment: I mean, by setting up a watch on jQuery in the debugger, one justs sees the whole thing at once - which makes it more easy to understand (in order to code oop, one need to know all properties and methods in the first place). e.g. ExtJS MVC is 70% debug, 30% code.